# Structure to represent matches between teams or individuals

Tags: database-design, normalization, relations

Say there's a sport that can either be contested between two individuals, or two teams comprised of several individuals. So obviously we need the standard `players`, `teams` and `teams_players` tables. But how do we design the related tables like `matches`, `competition_entries`, etc. (that need to reference either a player or a team) to accommodate this? I've come up two solutions, both have their drawbacks...

I could make a more generic `competitors(id, type, player_id, team_id)` table, where "type" is either `player` or `team`, and the last two columns reference the obvious tables, with precisely one of `player_id` and `team_id` being null. Then anything that needs to reference either a player or a team will reference the `competitors` table instead (e.g. in the `matches` table there'd be `competitor1_id` and `competitor2_id` columns). However, to my knowledge it would be impossible (within MySQL at least) to have appropriate constraints on this table - namely, that either one of `player_id` and `team_id` must be null, while the other one must be set.

The alternative which seems like a more "pure" solution but in practice is extremely long-winded, is just to have everything separate. Have a `team_matches` and an `individual_matches` table, have a `team_competitions` and an `individual_competitions` table, a `team_scores` and an `individual_scores`, etc... These tables will have mostly identical designs, except one will have a `player_id` column and the other `team_id`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
competitors(comp_id)
teams(team_id primary key, foreign key for competitors, other attributes)
players(player_id primary key, foreign key for competitors, other attributes)
matches(match_id primary key, first_comp_id foreign key for competitors, second_comp_id foreign key for competitors, other attributes)
```

and

```
teams_players(team_id foreign key for teams, player_id foreign key for players) primary key(team_id, player_id)
```

if the relation is many-to-many or simply an attribute team_id into player if the relation is one-to-many.